How to set up routing and firewall to achieve the desired result in this specific scenario (selective routing through wg tunnel)?
I have 2 linux computers connected via wireguard over the internet.
Their wg configuration is as follows.
Computer1:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <computer1-private-key>
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
ListenPort = 51820
[Peer]
PublicKey = <computer2-public-key>
PresharedKey = <preshared-key>
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.1/32

Computer2:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <computer2-private-key>
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
[Peer]
PublicKey = <computer1-public-key>
PresharedKey = <preshared-key>
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32

Computers 1 and 2 can ping each other through the tunnel, via 10.6.0.x IP address, and access any other services between themselves (ssh, http, etc.).
Currently, by default, any traffic from Computer1 to the internet goes directly, not through the wg tunnel. Also, any traffic from Computer2 to the internet goes directly, not through the wg tunnel.
That should stay that way.
What would have to be set up on computers 1 and 2, to forward through wg tunnel towards Computer2 and get outside to the internet on Computer2's side only the connections from a process executed by tuser account on Computer1?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
I tried setting up routing on Computer1 as follows:
echo "200 ttable" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tuser -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo ip rule add fwmark 1 table ttable
sudo ip route add default via 10.6.0.1 dev wg0 table ttable
sudo ip route add 10.6.0.1 dev wg0 table ttable
sudo ip route flush cache

On Computer2 I have enabled ip forwarding (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in sysctl.conf) and set the following on the fw:
sudoi ptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wg0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

If that's relevant, just to mention that the Computer2 has only wifi adapter.
When I try to test this configuration on Computer1 the following happens.
sudo -u tuser ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.111.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

sudo -u tuser curl 1.1.1.1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 80 after 0 ms: No route to host

What am I doing wrong?

On Computer1, the peer definition for Computer2 states AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.1/32, so WireGuard is only going to allow packets with a destination IP address of 10.6.0.1 to be sent to Computer2 (and only allow packets with a source IP address of 10.6.0.1 to be received from Computer2).
You need to change AllowedIPs on Computer1 to 0.0.0.0/0 to allow packets with any destination IP address to be sent to (and received from) Computer2. However, you don't want wg-quick to add a route for this to your main routing table; so also add a Table = off entry to the [Interface] section of Computer1's WireGuard config file -- or set Table = ttable if you want wg-quick to automatically add and remove routes to ttable for you that match your AllowedIPs settings:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <computer1-private-key>
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
ListenPort = 51820
Table = ttable
[Peer]
PublicKey = <computer2-public-key>
PresharedKey = <preshared-key>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0


Thank you very much. That's something that wasn't immediately obvious to me.
I have since gone through the documentation more thoroughly and looked different discussions. Now it's clear.
